# What is the best way to classify following words in POS tagging?

Tags: nlp

I am doing POS tagging. Given the following tokens in the training set, is it better to consider each token as Word1/POStag and Word2/POStag or consider them as one word that is Word1/Word2/POStag ?

Examples: (the POSTag is not required to be included)

```
Bard/EMS
Interstate/Johnson
Polo/Ralph
IBC/Donoghue
ISC/Bunker
Bendix/King
mystery/comedy
Jeep/Eagle
B/T
Hawaiian/Japanese
IBM/PC
Princeton/Newport
editing/electronic
Heller/Breene
Davis/Zweig
Fleet/Norstar
a/k/a
1/2
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Could you give some more information on context?  It's not clear what this is for.  Normally, Word1/POStag Word2/POStag is what you'd want to do, because Word1/Word2/POStag only ends up making sense for your particular training set, if that, which is a very limited use case.  That doesn't mean you should lose the information that you have from those words above being associated, though--but it would be preserved separately from POStags.

Comment: Those tokens above are from the training set. For example words like Interstate/Johnson might seem weird, but when I googled for "Interstate/Johnson", the first page had more "Interstate/Johnson" then "Interstate" "Johnson" as 2 separate words. On the other hand, words like "Polo/Ralph" have "Polo" "Ralph" as 2 separate words more often than they are together as one. I am trying to build a Language Model and you are right that my Language Model is bias to the training set I have. What I would want to know is, with such ambiguous word1/word2 appearing in my training set. .. to be continued

Comment: Should I consider that as 2 separate words that seems to be right most of the time, but it might be inaccurate sometimes, such as the word a/k/a, or Interstate/Johnson as mentioned earlier. So what should i do to make sure my Language Model doesn't lose out because of this inaccuracies? When i see a token like Fleet/Norstar/NNP, I am thinking if I should consider it as Fleet/NNP or Norstar/NNP or Fleet/Norstar/NNP, while building my Language Model.

Comment: @jdotjdot89 forget to tag you above

Comment: Ah, @John, wait, I think I understand--are each of those tokens you've listed above words that *include* a slash in them?  Like the phrase "a/k/a", including slashes?

Comment: @JohnLee that is an interesting question. It depepends on that you are trying to achieve I guess, but if these are important for the next step of the process, you might want to be on the safe side and treat them as unique words.

Answer (score 0):

The examples don't seem to fall into one category with respect to the use of the slash -- `a/k/a` is a phrase acronym, `1/2` is a number, `mystery/comedy` indicates something in between the two words, etc.
I feel there is no treatment of the component words that would work for all the cases in question, and therefore the better option is to handle them as unique words. At decoding stage, when the tagger will probably be presented with more previously unseen examples of such words, the decision can often be made based on the context, rather than the word itself.